# Repossession fee refund after 8 years

Tags: loans, fees

2013 our car was repossessed by WellsFargo Dealer Services
It was sold at auction and fell off my credit report this year. Today I received a check for$125 from an over charge of the repossession fee.
Is this some sort of subtrafuge or is a nice dividend from a poor lender?

Comment: what other paperwork came with the check? Did you look for all the microscopic footnotes referenced in the terms and conditions?

Comment: Does the paperwork mention the GAP (Guaranteed Asset/Auto Protection) product? See https://www.wellsfargo.com/help/customer-redress/